# Juniper networks firewall

Tags: juniper

I had Juniper networks which made block to websites so I want to prevent it from blocking any website what can I do?

Comment: Your question is unclear, please give more details.

Comment: It's probably blocked in an IPS rather than the device itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask your network administrator to lift the block. If you're an employee, circumventing such a system could be grounds for firing or other punishment.

Answer (score 1):

Which Juniper product are you using would be a good start for anyone to help you. I think your trying to say your being blocked by a webfilter hosted on Juniper equipment?

Are you an administrator or a user trying to bypass the system?

Comment: I am User on network and my web site blocked with webfilter hosted

Comment: Contact your network administrator.

Comment: The answer to your question is you dont. It is blocking access to websites as intended by your administrator. You will need to speak to him to either have the websites whitelisted your policy changed.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to disable Web filtering (Websense/SurfControl) or ask your admin to create a  filtering policy fitting your needs.